# Multiple environments for e2e testing w/ Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli

I am trying to create multiple environments setup for my e2e test but I can't find any specific information about this. I want to set multiple 'baseUrl' and probably 'seleniumAdress' properties regarding to the environment.

For example:

```
{
  'dev1': {
    baseUrl: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/',
    params: myParams
  },
  'dev2': {
    seleniumAddress: mySeleniumAddress,
    baseUrl: 'http://yyyyyyyyyyy.com/',
    params: myParams
  },
  'dev3': {
    seleniumAddress: mySeleniumAddress2,
    baseUrl: 'http://zzzzzzzzzzz.com/',
    params: myParams
  }
}
```

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951009/how-do-i-parameterize-the-baseurl-property-of-the-protractor-config-file Does this work for you?